# Am I missing a dll reference? IO.File.Move(ogPath, newPath, true) has too many arguments

Tags: .net, system.io.file

I have used `IO.File.Move(FileName, Destination, True)` in multiple projects, but for my current project my intellisense is not showing that method call. The only thing I can think of is that there is a dll file I have not referenced. Thank you in advance! <3

Comment: Have you checked the docs for [`Move`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=net-5.0)? Note that under each overload, there's a section that tells you *which .NET versions it applies to*. The 3 arg version appears to exist in far fewer versions than the 2 argument one.

Comment: I did not see that. The weird part is that I have used this method in another project that is using .Net 4.8 Framework just like I am using now. Is there any other way I could have managed to make that happen?

Comment: have you actually verified it's use in the other project or just remembering having used it? Because it mirrors a `Copy` overload that's existed for (forvever)

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. I went to verify if I was remembering correctly, I did use the `Copy` method and rather than `Move`. Sorry, I swore I used it, but my memory failed me. I guess I will just have to delete any existing file and then move the new files.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the namespace? Sometimes restarting Visual Studio solves this problem :)

C-Sharp:

```
using System.IO;
```

VB:

```
Imports System.IO
```

In .NET you should avoid "the double dot" because of garbage collection. File.Move(FileName, Destination, True) is better.

Comment: That last line is nonsense. Having `using System.IO;` and then `File.Move()` or having no `using` and using `IO.File.Move()` generates *exactly the same code*; It can thus make absolutely no difference at runtime, when garbage collection is a thing.

Comment: Yes, I have already imported the namespace. I can use the 2 argument method, just not the 3 argument method.